# How to open flutter using android phone?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, plugins

I'm having difficulty installing the flutter in my HUAWEI Y9 Prime mobile. I downloaded it on Chrome but there is no way to error. And I don't know what plugin should I use open the file Please help find out how thank you.

Comment: Flutter is framework for develop cross platform apps. it can't ddirectly run on any phone. You have to develop apps by using flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install flutter on your cell phones. You can follow [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install) link to install it on your system i.e: windows, mac